# What are the limitations of standalone SDL and why people choose to use an openGL context with it?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

One thing I keep seeing a lot is people using an openGL context with SDL, what's the reason for this?

It's not very intuitive to understand, if I use an openGL context my application will still be multiplatform? Will it run on iOS and Windows with the same code?

Comment: SDL doesn't itself draw any graphics; it's an abstraction layer and needs to know which graphics engine to use. See - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sdl/info

Comment: but you can draw graphics with SDL without using anything else, that's why Im confused

Comment: "Will it run on iOS and Windows with the same code" - no, mobile platforms used OpenGL ES instead, and now apple deprecated any form of OpenGL on both desktop and mobile. You have to use metal on ios/osx now. SDL provides only minimal functionality but it have multiple implementations for its renderer, so chances are your SDL code will work on other target without modification. If you want to combine 2d with 3d, or do some non-rectangular 2d, or use shaders on your sprites, do some heavy thing like rendering a lot of particles, etc. - SDL don't have you covered here.